# Cannot understand MVC5 + WebApi2 Authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

I know what is the concept of OAuth: User sends request to the server with grant type, username and password, after some checks on server, the user receives an access token.
What I cannot understand is why I should do this:

```
        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, GenerareProperties(user));
        context.Validated(ticket);
```

What is `CreateIdentityAsync` returning? What is an `AuthenticationTicket`? What does `context.Validated` do?
Also, If I have `oAuthIdentity` why should I also use `cookiesIdentity`? And finally, where is the access token being generated?

I searched but cannot find a website that explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateIdentityAsync` Will return the ClaimsIdentity to be used in the ClaimsPrincipal of the running context, which is further abstracted in...

An `AuthenticationTicket` is just a packaging of exactly what is passed in, for convenience.

`context.Validated` will add the information in the ticket to the current principal, and allow the OWIN pipeline to continue instead of returning a 401.

The reason for the `cookiesIdentity` is to allow authentication from the MVC pages in the template. It really is not used for the WebApi.

- Some Sources for further reading:

  - Here is a nice [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx?PageIndex=3) that describes the template from the RC, which was similar
  - Also here are [two](http://leastprivilege.com/) [blogs](http://brockallen.com/) where their authors break down parts of .NET security that might seem obscure